# Webflux Flux<Object> as spring boot service access using gateway through registry

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-webflux

I created a **(spring boot + webflux)** notification service which is working as independent service but,
when i integrate it with **Service Registry** and **Gateway** I am not able to get the Flux response from service.

It's waiting for some time after that giving 500 error.

As my service registry & gateway is common for other applications I can't turn them webflux enabled.
do we have any solution for this

Comment: well maybe you should figure out what the 500 error actually says, 500 is internal error. Internal error comes with an error message and a stacktrace. Maybe try looking there?

Comment: @ThomasAndolf tried but in actual service it's logging message is processed but it's not appearing on browser. also checked gateway and registry log, there is no stack trace available there

Comment: Then it is imossible to guess what is. Start by logging things properly. Good luck